# Is there a data structure other than stack for string reversal?

Tags: data-structures

I am exploring new data structures and their applications. Stack is very common data structure. I think there is a known popular data structure but I am being unable to recognize it's use here.

Comment: To reverse a string, one would typically use a for loop and exchange pairs of letters up to the middle.

Comment: @Phil1970 That is correct. I was curious to know if there was any data structure other than stack or let's say an alternative of stack that does the same task.

Comment: While other structure like a bidirectionnal list or an array could be used, there are not interesting either academically (you could do same with the string directly) or in practice (it add useless overhead). **Stack** in this case is only interesting from an academical point of view to help understanding push and pop effect on order.

Comment: AI useful exercise in understanding recursion is writing a recursive function that reverses a string, and then write the non-recursive version that uses an explicit stack. The recursive version of course uses stack frames--an *implicit* stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deque can be used to reverse a string